# blkdiag with multidimensional matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, diagonal

I have several multidimensional matrices and would like to stack them together diagonally like I would do with the function `blkdiag`if they were 2D.

You can find below a simple example of the operation I would like to perform:

```
% Matrices A and B are my inputs
A(:,:,1) = rand(5);
A(:,:,2) = rand(5);

B(:,:,1) = rand(5);
B(:,:,2) = rand(5);

% I would like the following output matrix
C(:,:,1) = blkdiag(A(:,:,1),B(:,:,1));
C(:,:,2) = blkdiag(A(:,:,2),B(:,:,2));
```

Comment: using `blkdiag` in a for loop is not an option ?

Comment: Yes, if there is nothing better that would be alright I guess.